# Are eigenvalues of A and B the same if B is a permutation of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $B$ be a permutation of $A$, such that the rows and columns have the same permutation. That is, if row 1 and row 2 are interchanged, then column 1 and column 2 are also interchanged.

Are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ the same? How are the eigenvectors affected?

Most of my searches bring up eigenvalues of permutation matrices or deal with only row permutations. Is there a name for this type of permutation? (So I know what to search for next time).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look up permutation matrices, and note that they are orthogonal matrices.  What happens to a matrix under an orthogonal similarity transformation?

Comment: Intuitively, you're just writing out the same linear transformation in a permutation of the basis.

Comment: Thank you @JairTaylor! Then yes, the eigenvalues are the same if it's a linear transformation in a permutation of the basis. It really just clicked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ is the permutation matrix for the rows
And $Q$ is the permutation matrix for the columns.

$B = PAQ$

now if we swap the columns like we do the rows.  How does $P$ relate to $Q$?

Particularity what is $PIQ$?

I say $PIQ = I \implies Q = P^{-1}$

and $B$ is similar to $A$

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is more concrete than my own hand-wavey justification.

Answer (score 1):

So to put it clearer, the eigenvalues do change, just consider this example:
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=\pm1, \text{ while } PA=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=\pm i$$
The product of all the eingenvalues (counting multiplicity) is invariant however.

However, if you apply the same transformation column and rows the two matrices are similar as remarked @Doug M